# Reading image from xlsx python won't work - I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python

I'm trying to read an image from a xlsx cell, should be simples but it keep raising errors.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl_image_loader import SheetImageLoader


filename = 'media/planilhas/tabela_de_simulador.xlsx'
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)

logos = workbook['operadoras']
image_loader = SheetImageLoader(logos)

image_loader.get('B2')
```

### I'm sure there is an image on the cell because when I change the cell, the error message says there's no image.
This is the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [108], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 image_loader.get('B2')

File ~/Documents/busqueplanodesaude/backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl_image_loader/sheet_image_loader.py:32, in SheetImageLoader.get(self, cell)
     30     raise ValueError("Cell {} doesn't contain an image".format(cell))
     31 else:
---> 32     image = io.BytesIO(self._images[cell]())
     33     return Image.open(image)

File ~/Documents/busqueplanodesaude/backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/drawing/image.py:64, in Image._data(self)
     60 def _data(self):
     61     """
     62     Open image and write it to a buffer when saving the workbook
     63     """
---> 64     img = _import_image(self.ref)
     65     fp = None
     66     # don't convert these file formats

File ~/Documents/busqueplanodesaude/backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/drawing/image.py:33, in _import_image(img)
     30     raise ImportError('You must install Pillow to fetch image objects')
     32 if not isinstance(img, PILImage.Image):
---> 33     img = PILImage.open(img)
     35 return img

File ~/Documents/busqueplanodesaude/backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py:3096, in open(fp, mode, formats)
   3093     exclusive_fp = True
   3095 try:
-> 3096     fp.seek(0)
   3097 except (AttributeError, io.UnsupportedOperation):
   3098     fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

**Someone has any idea on this?**

Comment: Yes it appears the image is found OK, the error occurs when  Openpyxl uses Pillow to determine what the file type is. Pillow is trying to read the magic number and fails with I/O on closed file error. The error text might be misleading. I don't see any issue with your code I ran a test on Python 3.8. So either module versions or perhaps the image itself. If possible I'd ensure your modules are all the latest releases. What type of image is it (png, jpeg, etc)? Have you tried another image(s) in your Excel sheet as in it happens with all images or just one?

Comment: Take this up with whoever developed openpyxl_image_loader

Comment: I tried with Jpg and png, and none works. Does someone knows another package to read imagem from xls or xlsx?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your excel file. Your image is out of cell boundaries. Make sure that the pictures are within the cell boundaries!